# Adding Visual WorkFlows in Lightning Page

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, flow, visual-flows

I am trying to add flow in lightning page using the lightning app builder. 
I have gone through [Winter 17 Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_lab.htm?edition=&impact=) and found that we can do it. To add more information, I am using the winter 17 dev org and I have checked the Enable Lightning Runtime for Flows (Beta) checkbox from the Process Automation Settings.

Thanks

Comment: Am I reading the same as you.. I see it only mentioned that the flows will now run "Lightning Skin".  It means only the look and feel of the flows will be Lightning like.   Can you confirm that indeed "we can add flows to lightning page using lightning app builder"?

Comment: I have edited the link, Please check now

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the flow(BETA) component from app builder and drop that

[image]

[image]

There is also a great blogpost explaining the [procedure](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/08/30/flow-in-winter17-lightning-experience/)

Comment: I tried in the Winter 17 Dev org, Not sure If I am missing something or that is possible in this org

Comment: Do we need to get support to enable the Beta or is it GA?

Comment: It's available in dev edition org .Its in BETA .Reach SFDC Incase you do not see ut

Comment: @krishsfdc Winter 17 dev orgs are not yet available .How did you get one ? Only pre release orgs are available

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, Its a pre release dev org. My bad.

Comment: @krishsfdc Can you DM me .My mail Id is above .I can help troubleshooting it .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution however I can think of is - Embed a flow into a visualforce page as usual. Now using Lightning App Builder, drag and drop the visualforce page into your Lightning Page.  That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Yes, I knew that,  I am interested to add it directly